# How to configure Azure ACS to return SAMLResponse parameter instead of RSTR xml?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, wif, saml-2.0, acs

[image: how ACS authentication works]

I have [SSO login setup with Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-dotnet-how-to-use-access-control/) similar to the one above:

In the POST request (6&7) from ACS at my application (RP) end, I am getting:

~~~~~~~~

POST

wa: wsignin1.0

wresult: RSTR XML - ([example format - data removed](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4d0557e11e7962dce3d9))

~~~~~~~~

whereas what my RP expects and understand is a SAMLResponse request parameter.

**How can I configure Azure/ACS so that it returns SAMLResponse as a parameter in POST request.**

I cannot change application (RP) to handle RSTR as of now and without SAMLResponse application cannot verify/authenticate the SAML Response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAMLResponse is part of the SAML2p protocol - ACS does not support that. Maybe have a look at Azure AD instead -

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/02/12/the-future-of-azure-acs-is-azure-active-directory.aspx

Comment: But wikipedia says that ACS supports SAML 2.0                  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Control_Service

Comment: I would prefer a Microsoft documentation that states the same. Also - on your way in you use WS-Federation - this will for sure not generate a SAML2p response.

Comment: Agree, as per msdn, ACS supports SAML2.0 for security token but not for the protocol used to transfer that toke. Thanks for clarification. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg185950.aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg185948.aspx